# Error in module during network setup:

Tags: omnet++

Class not found perhaps it was not linked in or the class wasn't registered with Register_Class(), or in the case of modules and channels, with Define_Module()/Define_Channel().

Comment: Just like the error message says, your class / module / channel was not defined or registered. There are tons of messages on the OMNeT mailing list concerning this topic. You should check your code and the [OMNeT manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/) to learn more about OMNeT modules and how to register them.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested you should use

```
Define_Module(yourModule)
```

in your .cc file.

If this gives error, check that all the functions listed in *yourModule.h* have been also declared in *yourModule.cc*